# Order of dimensions for matrices and data points

Tags: matrices, education

During early school-days I was taught that $2$-dimensional data points are described by $(a,b)$ where $a$ refers to the value of the $x$-axis and $b$ to the value of the $y$-axis.

Later I learned that matrices are mostly defined by $(m\times n)$ where $m$ refers to the number of rows and $n$ to the number of columns.

I am not sure if this is specific for me, but by starting to think from a two-dimensional area and then learning the notation for matrices always confused me, because of the reversed order.

Is there a reason for the kind of "reversed" order?

Comment: It is not a reversion of the order. These are different things.

Comment: I added some quotes around _reversed_. Of course I know that these are different things and the order is not really reversed. Nevertheless it might be useful to understand the reason for the order to keep it in mind. @user202723 thanks for pointing out the lack of clarity.